# Clean old SP users

Tags: 2010, delete

I look for synchronize my SP users regarding to the AD users.

I thought that I remove a user in AD, it would be removed from SP but not at all!

How can I remove all users in SharePoint deleted in AD ? What are the risks of such an operation ?

Comment: my "Hello" disapears...

Comment: ok, matter of politeness ;)

Comment: Alas some editors are really fanatic about deleting all politeness from SO. As for your question, search for (hidden) **User Information List** and you'll get some more info

Comment: ahem! You are a very good critic! Your points against fanatic editors should be listed here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 0):

Write a timer job for accomplishing it. Followings can be the steps

1. Iterate over the SP Users
2. Check if user exists in AD
3. If user exists in AD, then continue
4. If user does not exist in AD, then remove from SP

Following article may help you a bit. It explained how to sync AD users to a SharePoint list.

[How to Synchronize Active Directory Users to a SharePoint List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1029168/How-to-Synchronize-Active-Directory-Users-to-a-Sha)

Comment: Hi, what about for documents , workflows ... that belonged to the deleted users ?

Comment: Yeah. You have asked two questions. You can take action for deleted users based on your requirements.

Comment: Hi. ok Atish. Can you explain me how to run your script please ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run the partial or full sync on central admin user profile service once deleted on AD. it wont show up strait away but after several syncs.

so to speed it up if you cant wait for sharepoint to handle it through normal setup timerjobs and timed syncs you can run the following timer job in central admin:

"My Site Cleanup" Timer job that should purge the profiles marked for deletion :)

**EDIT**

as a beginner you should use msdn for great info.... sometimes :)

to run a sync:

1) goto central admin on your server

2) on the menu items to the left click on "Application Managment"

3) within the main body area under "Service Applications" click on "Manage Service Applications"

4) a new page will load with all running services. Find and click on User "Profile Service Application". it might be named slightly differently. if so look under Type column.

5) you should now be directed to the correct place. Under "Synchronization" you can click on "Start Profile Synchronization"

6) lastly you can either do incremental or full sync. In your case do incremental several times as its quicker.

every time you do an incremental crawl it would take you back to the previous page. on that page to the right you can see  "Profile Synchronization Settings". under that heading you can see two rows. The one your interested in is "Profile Synchronization Status" as it generates a report on the craw that you can click on to view.

once above steps are complete then run the timerjob and you should see a difference.

Comment: hi, I found the timer job as you talk about. Web Application : Not applicable 
Frequency : every hour

but it doesn't seem to work in fact.

Comment: did you run a partial sync on user profile service atleast a couple of times as it doesnt pick any changes the first time. you can see the report once complete.

Comment: Thx a lot ! I'm really beginner. Can you explain me how to run a sync please ?

Comment: just ammended the answer :)

Comment: Hi all and thanks, I display something but I get this red message : The connection of this user profile application is currently unavailable. The application pool or User Profile Service has perhaps not been started. Contact the administrator. When I click on "Start Profile Synchronization" I get a ID correlation issue. Foundation limitation ? :(